# Mirroring PWM input on a pin + Motor Encoder

Tags: atmega328, atmega

I am interested in hooking up a nano to an RC receiver. I want the nano to mirror the PWM input and output on another pin when a specific command is given via serial. I also want to send the received command via serial to a computer(Pi or Jetson) at the same update rate.

I can run pin change interrupt on the input pins to basically enable/disable the pins but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

I also will be updating a motor encoder at pin change interrupt, I'm guessing around 4k interrupts/second.

Do you think the Nano provides enough juice or I should use a Pico?

Comment: You haven't mentioned the PWM frequency nor did you mention the baudrate of the serial. But if we do the math here, classic Nano runs on 16MHz i.e. per cycle is 62.5 nanoseconds. That's plenty if juice if you do everything right.